# Pandaic approach to iterating over a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm making a test-team report from excel input; using pandas to gather, filter, process data.

I made below code to make product-testcase cover table for later use/easy search. With 3rd column being type of test case. I have multiple testcases inside one excel  so I need to go through all of cells and split tests to make pairs product - test case.

Because I'm not much familiar with pandas and I haven't found better way elsewhere I would like to ask if there is more pythonic way or easier in pandas way to do the same and more efficient.

code with example data ( \n is newline inside excel cell):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"prod":["TS001","TS002"], 
                   "activate":["001_002\n001_004", "003_008\n024_080"],
                   "deactivate":["004_005\n006_008", "001_008"]})
df = df.set_index("prod")

list_of_tuples = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for cell in row.iteritems():
        for test in cell[-1].splitlines():
            list_of_tuples.append((i, test, cell[0]))  # [(product, test, category)..]

return_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns=('prod', 'testcase', 'category'))
```

producing:

```
    prod testcase    category
0  TS001  001_002    activate
1  TS001  001_004    activate
2  TS001  004_005  deactivate
3  TS001  006_008  deactivate
4  TS002  003_008    activate
5  TS002  024_080    activate
6  TS002  001_008  deactivate
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(p, t, c) for (p, c), r in df.stack().items() for t in r.split()],
    columns=['prod', 'testcase', 'category']
)

    prod testcase    category
0  TS001  001_002    activate
1  TS001  001_004    activate
2  TS001  004_005  deactivate
3  TS001  006_008  deactivate
4  TS002  003_008    activate
5  TS002  024_080    activate
6  TS002  001_008  deactivate
```

---

**Explanation**

```
df.stack()

prod             
TS001  activate      001_002\n001_004
       deactivate    004_005\n006_008
TS002  activate      003_008\n024_080
       deactivate             001_008
dtype: object
```

When iterating over `df.stack().items()`, we get tuples with index value as the first element and value as the second element.  Because we stacked, the index value itself is a tuple.  So the first pair looks like:

```
(('TS001', 'activate'), '001_002\n001_004')
```

Through subsequent iteration over `'001_002\n001_004'.split()` and rearranging the unpacked elements, we get

```
[(p, t, c) for (p, c), r in df.stack().items() for t in r.split()]

[('TS001', '001_002', 'activate'),
 ('TS001', '001_004', 'activate'),
 ('TS001', '004_005', 'deactivate'),
 ('TS001', '006_008', 'deactivate'),
 ('TS002', '003_008', 'activate'),
 ('TS002', '024_080', 'activate'),
 ('TS002', '001_008', 'deactivate')]
```

I then wrap this in a `pd.DataFrame` constructor where I name the columns.

Comment: I'm observing this, your late fascination with convoluted comprehensions ;) and a neat answer!

Comment: I tend to abuse one dimension at a time.  I went through a `query` phase, a `pd.factorize` phase, a `stack` phase.  Even a `pokemon` phase.... wait, that isn't relevant!

Comment: Sir, please add benchmarks if you can. I think, this much efficient than the rest by a large factor, and this answer deserves much attention.

Comment: This does seem really good. Thank you for the explanation.

One clarification for others, this answer goes after: 

df = df.set_index('prod')

Comment: This is so neat and clean.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) like your solution
- [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for working with multiple columns with lambda function for `DataFrame` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and `expand=True` and reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for columns to `Multiindex`
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) first for remove level and then for `Multiindex` to columns
- rename column
- [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) for change order of columns

---

```
df = (df.set_index('prod')
        .apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n', expand=True).unstack())
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='testcase')
        .rename(columns={'level_1':'category'})
        .reindex_axis(['prod','testcase','category'], axis=1))
print (df)
    prod testcase    category
0  TS001  001_002    activate
1  TS001  004_005  deactivate
2  TS002  003_008    activate
3  TS002  001_008  deactivate
4  TS001  001_004    activate
5  TS001  006_008  deactivate
6  TS002  024_080    activate
```

Comment: I'm afraid, this will not work if there is another row with `prod` equals to `TS001` or `TS002`?

Comment: Not sure, dont test it. I have to go away, so later.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! it really works. I wasn't able to make the apply / applymap working myself so I ended with the for loops.

Comment: I have one improvement, give me a sec.

Comment: The prods should be unique. Though I guess you should never trust someone else's input. :)

Comment: Yes, need unstack instead stack, then it working nice generally.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way and there could be better ways of doing it. Check [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195074/2137255)'s - should be the most efficient among the ones here.

```
In [2807]: (df.set_index('prod')
              .applymap(lambda x: x.split('\n'))
              .stack()
              .apply(pd.Series)
              .stack()
              .reset_index(name='testcase')
              .rename(columns={'level_1': 'category'})
              .drop('level_2', 1))
Out[2807]:
    prod    category testcase
0  TS001    activate  001_002
1  TS001    activate  001_004
2  TS001  deactivate  004_005
3  TS001  deactivate  006_008
4  TS002    activate  003_008
5  TS002    activate  024_080
6  TS002  deactivate  001_008
```

Details

```
In [2809]: df
Out[2809]:
           activate        deactivate   prod
0  001_002\n001_004  004_005\n006_008  TS001
1  003_008\n024_080           001_008  TS002
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I was looking into apply / applymap but couldn't get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Using *`df.applymap`*, *`df.melt`*,  and *`df.stack`*

```
df = df.applymap(str.split).reset_index().melt('prod', \
              ['activate', 'deactivate']).set_index(['prod', 'variable'])
df = pd.DataFrame(df.value.tolist(), index=df.index)\
                         .stack().reset_index().drop('level_2', 1) 
df.columns = ['prod', 'category', 'testcase']

df
    prod    category testcase
0  TS001    activate  001_002
1  TS001    activate  001_004
2  TS002    activate  003_008
3  TS002    activate  024_080
4  TS001  deactivate  004_005
5  TS001  deactivate  006_008
6  TS002  deactivate  001_008
```